# jest test failing with error "Class constructor Stack cannot be invoked without 'new'"

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, jestjs, aws-cdk

I got this  jest test for an  aws-cdk configuration

```
import { expect as expectCDK, matchTemplate, MatchStyle } from '@aws-cdk/assert';
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { KmsMultiregionPrincipalKey } from '../lib/kms_multiregion_principalkey-stack';


test('Not Empty Stack', () => {
   const app = new cdk.App();
   // WHEN
   const stack = new KmsMultiregionPrincipalKey(app, 'MyTest_KmsMultiRegionKeyStack');
   // THEN
   // expectCDK(stack).to(matchTemplate({
   //   "Resources": {}
   // }, MatchStyle.EXACT))
});
```

The KmsMultiregionPrincipalKey class is declared as under

```
export class KmsMultiregionPrincipalKey extends cdk.Stack {
 public readonly principalKeyArn: string;

 constructor(scope: cdk.Construct, id: string, props?: cdk.StackProps) {
   super(scope, id, props);

// REST OF THE CLASS CODE HERE
}
}}
```

For more details below are *tsconfig.json*, and *jest.config.json* files:

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
 "compilerOptions": {
   "target": "ES2018",
   "module": "commonjs",
   "lib": [
     "es2018"
   ],
   "declaration": true,
   "strict": true,
   "noImplicitAny": true,
   "strictNullChecks": true,
   "noImplicitThis": true,
   "alwaysStrict": true,
   "noUnusedLocals": false,
   "noUnusedParameters": false,
   "noImplicitReturns": true,
   "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
   "inlineSourceMap": true,
   "inlineSources": true,
   "experimentalDecorators": true,
   "strictPropertyInitialization": false,
   "typeRoots": [
     "./node_modules/@types"
   ]
 },
 "exclude": [
   "node_modules",
   "cdk.out"
 ]
}
```

**jest.config.json**

```
module.exports = {
 testEnvironment: 'node',
 roots: ['<rootDir>/test'],
 testMatch: ['**/*.test.ts'],
 transform: {
   '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
 }
};
```

When I run the test I got the following error

**``Class constructor Stack cannot be invoked without 'new'```**

Question: What is wrong with my test or jest/typescript configurations?

To give you more context this test where all except the app definition is commented, pass:

PASSING TEST

```
import { expect as expectCDK, matchTemplate, MatchStyle } from '@aws-cdk/assert';
import * as cdk from '@aws-cdk/core';
import { KmsMultiregionPrincipalKey } from '../lib/kms_multiregion_principalkey-stack';


test('Not Empty Stack', () => {
   const app = new cdk.App();
   // WHEN
   //const stack = new KmsMultiregionPrincipalKey(app, 'MyTest_KmsMultiRegionKeyStack');
   // THEN
   // expectCDK(stack).to(matchTemplate({
   //   "Resources": {}
   // }, MatchStyle.EXACT))
});
```

Comment: If the commented out line `expectCDK(stack).to` is uncommented it could potentially throw that error because when you pass a function to Jest it will try to call it.

Comment: If the code below ```const stack ...``` is un-commented, it still fails the same way. If I comment all the code starting at ```const stack ...```, the test pass. So the issue is with the ```const stack ...``` definition

Comment: Can you check what the actually executed (transpiled) code looks like? Make sure it's actually using `class` syntax with `super`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was just updating node.

```
node --version
14.x...
nvm install --lst
node --version
16.13.0
```

That simple update makes it work

Does "module": "commonjs" need node > 14 ?

Comment: No, `"module": "commonjs"` does not need node > 14